# Entity Framework with many to many relationship generetad tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, models, controllers

Here's my question. I have 2 models (Person, Event) and with EF and modelbuilder I generate a booking table (with IdPerson and IdEvent as properties).
So in my DB it's correct, I have 3 tables (Person, Event and Booking) with many to many relationship. But I have only 2 models in Visual Studio (Booking doesn't exist because of the self-generated table).
With my Controller I want to write an action for the Person to suscribe to an event and I have to write on my table Booking on the DB but it doesn't exist as a model so I can't do that .
How should I proceede?
Should I create a Booking model and delete my modelbuilder?

Comment: Person should have an eventlist (List<Event>), add the event you want to subscribe to to that list

Comment: I've already that but my question is how can I access to the table booking in my DB if it doesn't exist as a class (model).
In my controller I need to do an action that get the id from Person and id from Event and then write it in the db table Booking as a new booking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using ORMs like EF, you can sit back and let the ORM manage these middle tables.

You can use

`person.Events.Add(event)`

or

`event.People.Add(event)`

and EF handles all and inserts a row with `personId` and `eventId` in that table.

Here you can find a complete sample:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/05/14/code-first-ef-4-1-building-many-to-many-relationship.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try

Comment: I understood the concept but how can i get the ID from the user I want to put in my EventModel?

Comment: In other words, I have a Personne with a UserId which is connected and i need to get the id to put on the reservation

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a model first approach.

The reason for having only 2 objects is that, by default, EF does not create objects for joint tables. What it does create is Navigation Property ([Entity Framework - Navigation Property Basics](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/7/17/entity_framework-navigation_property_basics_with_code_first)). In one-to-many scenario, a navigation property inside a parent object contains a collection of entities in a foreign / child table. In many-to-many scenario, navigation properties of each entities will simply contain collections of its other entities.